# Умные указатели (shared_ptr)

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

`foo` - указатель на объект родителя A

`auto bar = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(foo);` - присваивание указателю дочернего класса указатель на родительский объект(???)

Как это работает? Если только указатель родительского класса может содержать ссылки на дочерние объекты, но не наоборот

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A {
    static const char* static_type;
    const char* dynamic_type;
    A() { dynamic_type = static_type; }
};
struct B : A {
    static const char* static_type;
    B() { dynamic_type = static_type; }
};

const char* A::static_type = "class A";
const char* B::static_type = "class B";

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> foo;
    std::shared_ptr<B> bar;

    foo = std::make_shared<A>();

    bar = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(foo);

    std::cout << "foo's static  type: " << foo->static_type << '\n';
    std::cout << "foo's dynamic type: " << foo->dynamic_type << '\n';
    std::cout << "bar's static  type: " << bar->static_type << '\n';
    std::cout << "bar's dynamic type: " << bar->dynamic_type << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo's static  type: class A
foo's dynamic type: class A
bar's static  type: class B
bar's dynamic type: class A
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::static_pointer_cast` - это на самом деле обычный `static_cast`. Просто для умных указателей. Если посмотреть в возможные реализации на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast), то это стает очевидно.

Собственно, проблема сводится к более простой.

```
A* a = new A;
B* b = static_cast<B*>(b);
```

А все потому что это такой каст. Он просто проверяет что два класса находятся в правильной иерархии наследования. И делает он это на этапе компиляции. А в этот момент настоящие типы не известны (на самом деле компилятор мог бы и догадаться, и ошибку компиляции показать, но...) `dynamic_cast`/`dynamic_pointer_cast` все бы нашел и возвратил бы `nullptr`.

p.s. в Вашем примере есть небольшая ошибка - он не компилируется. переменная foo объявлена дважды.